# Why does QGIS keep freezing?

Tags: qgis

About a year ago I installed the newest version of QGIS, but it kept freezing after  a few minutes of use, so I uninstalled it and installed 2.18 because it was supposed to be more stable. It seemed to work at the time. Not until the last few weeks have I really started to use QGIS intensively, and now it has started freezing again. I haven't been doing anything complicated, just creating polygons and editing their attributes. It doesn't seem to matter exactly what i'm trying to do, after a certain time or number of clicks the whole thing just freezes and won't function no matter how long I wait.

I've seen similar questions, but without any definitive answers. I'm running Windows 10 on an MSI 72. The computer should definitely be fast enough, I never had a problem with ArcGIS or AutoCAD. I haven't installed any plugins, and I don't see how it could be a problem with the data as I'm creating it in QGIS and it doesn't matter if I'm editing the data or just trying to zoom in/out.

Comment: How big is your dataset?

Comment: 413 polygons at the moment, but Like I said it doesn't matter if i editing it or not.

Comment: How big in MB? Are they simple geometries or very large and very complex? Are they stored remotely or locally? Shapefile or GeoPackage or something else? There's a lot of seemingly extraneous details that can help people answer the question, since, for most people, QGIS doesn't freeze without cause.

Comment: Have you got any plugins installed?

Comment: Less than 1 MB, they're all simple polygons like rectangles, stored locally on my computer as shapefiles. And no I haven't installed any plugins. The problem isn't with this particular dataset, whether I load a different vector file or just a small raster, it will eventually freeze. It works fine at first, but no matter what I do or don't do it will freeze when I click on something, it doesn't matter what.

Comment: I have add problem with the Acceleration option (the "Enable OpenCL acceleration" checkbox) you could try to look at the state of this option on your installation and see what happen when you change it